# How do I convert string variables to numeric variables in Stata?

Tags: string, variables, numeric, stata

I have two variables in Stata, both numeric variables that have somehow been recorded as string variables. I need them converted to numeric variables so that I can generate a new variable with them.

When I tried, it said `type mismatch` I have tried the `real` and the `encode` commands, none of which are working.

Comment: It always help to show _exactly_ what code you tried. Note that `real()` is a function in Stata, not a command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `destring var, replace` in Stata if you want to convert `var` into numeric

Or,

```
encode var, generate(var1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i realised it was string because there were some 'NA' in the dataset, i deleted them and it was fine. !

Answer (score 0):

```
destring varname, replace ignore(xyz)
```

`xyz` is any non-numeric character in the value of the variable